# in Java, why can't i pass an invocation string longer than 94 chars to Runtime.getRuntime().exec()?

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime.exec

I'm trying to invoke a .bat file from a java app. Seems simple, yet I'm having 2 problems and would really appreciate some advice:

1. The code below fails to execute the bat file because the argument string is longer than 94 chars. if i use exactly 94 chars (by removing the trailing 'x' from the end of the `clientArgs` string) the bat file executes ok.
   (same problem if i use the alternative invocation and pass the args as `String[]`)
   anyway, i need to be able to pass much longer command strings (~150 chars)
2. If I modify the `clientArgs` to not include the full file name but only the short name (since I'm specifying the working directory) I get:

   `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "client.bat" (in directory "C:\2\code\FlaFl\flafl-0.7-RC2"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String CMD_FILE_NAME = "client.bat"; //cmd or bat - still limit'n is 94 chars
    String cmdFileFolder= "C:/2/code/FlaFl/flafl-0.7-RC2/"; 
    File workingDir = new File(cmdFileFolder);
    String clientArgs = cmdFileFolder + 
         CMD_FILE_NAME + " -host name12.mycompanyname3.com -app hive"
         + "123456789 34x";  //95 chars fails. remove the x to get it to work
    System.out.println("length of invoc str is "+clientArgs.length());
    Process process=null;
    try {
         process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(clientArgs,null,workingDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("exception "+e);
    }
    //sleep(2000);
    //if (process!=null)
    //    process.destroy();
}
```

Comment: And what if you replace the final `x` with a number (let say `5`)? `:)`

Comment: are you sure batch file is in dir `C:\2\code\FlaFl\flafl-0.7-RC2` ?

Comment: the batch file is there. to make sure, i copy the directory from the console of eclipse and do a DIR of that and i can see it there

Comment: Btw, my batch file simply contains one line:

Comment: after execution of the java code i view foo.txt to see if the params i sent it were appended to foo.txt. this is how i decide if it ran or not

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMAND.COM

> The command line length in interactive mode is limited to 126 characters.

This could be the cause of your problem.

You can create a `.bat` file and run it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Java Doc of Exec suggests

> ProcessBuilder.start() is now the preferred way to start a process with a modified environment.

Comment: ok, but i'm not trying to modify the environment of the started process

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String CMD_FILE_NAME = "client.bat"; // cmd or bat - still limit'n is 94
                                            // chars
    String cmdFileFolder = "C:/2/code/FlaFl/flafl-0.7-RC2/";
    File workingDir = new File(cmdFileFolder);
    String clientArgs = CMD_FILE_NAME
            + " -host name12.mycompanyname3.com -app hive"
            + "123456789 34x"; // 95 chars fails. remove the x to get it to
                                // work
    System.out.println("length of invoc str is " + clientArgs.length());
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(clientArgs, null, workingDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception " + e);
    }
    // sleep(2000);
    // if (process!=null)
    // process.destroy();
}
```

you are giving `cmdFileFolder` in command i.e. working directory in code while you are passing `workingDir` to `Runtime.exec()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to replicate your problem, I successfully run commands with much much much much longer argument line.
Try to insert

```
  try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

after you execute your command (in place of those commented `sleep() ...`) to make sure you allow it to finish.

There is actually another problem with this approach (which I initially thought may be your problem) - if your process writes enough data to fill it's console buffer it may block, as described here (javadoc for process):

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for
>   standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
>   stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the
>   subprocess to block, or even deadlock.

so you should read it first:

```
InputStream is=process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String line=new String();
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) System.out.println (line);  //do something real here
```

If you do not want to read your bat output (and I do not see you do) you can skip all that and just run your command in it's separate window:
`cmd /c start \"my command\" c:/temp/startup.bat args`

(note about second form with working dir, use `cmd /c startup.bat arguments` to get rid of that 'not found' exception)

Comment: thanks for the very informative response. have you tried to invoke a bat file with the echo statement as i described above? i noticed that it's working for some commands but not for the echo for some reason. in response to some of your comments: 1) the echo does not wait for input so there is no reason to open the input stream. 2)  i don't want to wait for the process to complete - i need to kill it after a few seconds (my problem is that the invocation immediately fails 3) is it a must or better to invoke Cmd rather than specify the name of the .bat file?

Comment: yes I run it with exact `echo %*`. As soon as it starts to write to console (and commands are echoed to console) it will fail (if you do not read it). Try with `@echo` or call with `cmd /q /c`. ad 1) This is a bit convoluted, this `InputStream` is actually **output** of your command. ad 2) make sure it does not write to stdout - use `@echo off` or `cmd /q` or use `ProcessBuilder` to redirect it's streams. ad 3) it was the only way I was able to run it without specifying full path. Otherwise I believe they are effectively equal (less control on cmd.exe invocation parameters)